# Wolverine in the river at the end of X-Men: Days of Future Past

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past

Wolverine had been in the river for a full day before he was dredged up by Striker. He can regenerate, but how does he come back from the dead?

Comment: I missed the fact that he'd been in the river a very extended period of time.  How is this shown?

Comment: How do you consider he was actually dead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The movies have not really examined the extent of Wolverine's ability to regenerate.  In the comics they have been dramatically extended over the years to the point where he can survive being near the centre of a nuclear explosion.

Specifically on the issue of drowning, the story arc "Drowning Logan" (Wolverine (vol. 5) #5 (Jun. 2013). Marvel Comics.) specifically covers what happens when he is trapped underwater for an extended period.  This damages his long term health, but does not kill him.

Ref: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolverine_%28character%29#Healing_and_defensive_powers)

Comment: The beginning of that paragraph about drowning states that it's actually a potential method of killing him, though... "*He has stated that he is not particularly fond of being in water, due partially to the additional weight of his adamantium laced skeleton, and that he can die if held under water long enough with his healing factor only prolonging the agony.*"

Comment: @Catija - but then goes on to say there are stories where he survives extended periods underwater.  Unfortunately superhero powers are a flexible device used by the writers.  I was trying to illustrate that its not unprecedented to have him survive being trapped underwater.

Comment: So true. I think the dodgy part here is that he likely enters some sort of stasis that maintains his life for some period of time but that that time is not infinite. Eventually, he will die. What is unclear is whether it's a matter of days or weeks or years.